# File filtering in data factory based on last successful run date

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have files in SFTP that get uploaded every week. The files have a name with the date appended to it. I want to copy only the newest files every week into adls. Whenever the job is completed successfully the date is stored in a sql table so I can look up the last successful run date.

In my mind I think I need something like this: filter files whose name contains a date greater than or equal to last successful run date.... or filter files whose last modified date is greater or equal to last successful run date?

This way if the job failed on the last run it will grab the previous weeks and the current weeks files.

Currently my pipeline has a lookup that can show me the last successful run, get meta data that shows all the files in the sftp folder, filter, and for each(copy). I know the copy works because I set the filter for a specific file and it worked. The area I need help with is the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by using using a tumbling window trigger to plug in the last successful run date and current date variables into the last modified parameters in the get metadata activity. I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-copy-new-files-lastmodifieddate) as a guide

Answer (score 0):

I create a sample to test and hope this can help you:

[image: total]

I set a pipeline variable `LastRunDate` type is `string`,value is "2020-07-01" which like your output of `lookup activity`.

Here is the output of my `GetMetaData Activity`:

```
{
    "childItems": [
        {
            "name": "polo_2020-06-30.csv",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "polo_2020-07-01.csv",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "polo_2020-07-02.csv",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ]
}
```

The setting of `Filter Activity`:

"items":`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

"Condition":`@greater(split(split(item().name,'_')[1],'.')[0],variables('LastRunDate'))`

Here is the output of `Filter Activity`:

```
{
    "ItemsCount": 3,
    "FilteredItemsCount": 1,
    "Value": [
        {
            "name": "polo_2020-07-02.csv",
            "type": "File"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is useful. I ended up solving my problem by using using a tumbling window trigger to plug in the last successful run date and current date variables into the last modified parameters in the get metadata activity. I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-copy-new-files-lastmodifieddate) as a guide

Comment: Congratulation!You can try to mark your answer and  this can be beneficial to other community members.